# No "ground" layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, layer

Just learning unity for game development. Absolute beginner and following a tutorial. There it says that you must add a layer "ground" to the prefabs to let the player know when he is on the ground so that you are not able to start jumping from any point in the scene. But when I go into my layer menu, there isn't an option for ground.

[image]

The option is there when they do it on the tutorial. Any ideas why it's missing and how to add it?

Many thanks,

P

Answer (score 1):

There's no pre-built ground layer in the Layer Mask of Unity.
You have to add it. Just click the **Add Layer** label and create a layer.
More about layers here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html